# How do i add textview in android without using XML

Tags: android

how can i add textview without using XML. I am using Eclipse. Thanks

Comment: First try And add your code when Any Error you face,and try with search engine....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search on google: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/  :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
 ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
 tv.setText("Dynamic layouts ftw!");
 ll.addView(tv);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to add it to a parentView

```
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
parentView.addView(tv);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without you being more specific, this is the best I can do.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle orSomething) 
    {
        super.onCreate(orSomething);
        setContentView(new TextView(this));
    }
}
```